# Android: put view at same height as other view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I've got a LinearLayout (vertical horizontation), containing 2 RelativeLayouts, which contain 1 button each.
In the left RelativeLayout, the button is centered in parent. In the right RelativeLayout there's a slightly bigger button.
I want the bottom of that bigger button te be at the same height of the other button. Like so:

[image]

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the bottom position and width of the smaller button using getBottom() and getWidth respectively in **onWindowFocusChanged**.

Create the other button at run-time. Set top padding to second relative layout as bottom_position of button1 - height_of_button2.

Add this button to the second relative layout after setting the desired height and width (obtained from getWidth of butoon1).

Here is the sample:-

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        relative_layout_two = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl2);
        int bottom_position_of_button1 = bt1.getBottom();
        int width_of_button1 = bt1.getWidth();
        bt2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        rl.setPadding(0, bottom_position_of_button1-200, 0, 0);// I have taken 200 as the height of second button
        rl.addView(bt2, width_of_button1, 200);

    };
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: BTW, is it ok if I do this in onCreate() instead of in onWindowFocusChanged?

Comment: BTW2, do I get the width and bottom position in dip or px?

Comment: They are in pixels. Though you can convert it to dip as well.

Comment: No you cannot do it in onCreate() b'coz by then the views are not laid. So, you cannot get the positions and sizes in onCreate(). onWindowFocusChanged() is called only after the layout is laid. So it is the good time to get the required data.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:layout_alignParentBottom on both buttons, and then apply a android:layout_marginBottom of the same value on both.

Comment: Well, than the left button isn't necessarily in the middle, is it?

Comment: I am not sure if you can keep it centered and align both to the same distance from the bottom. Unless you are willing to do the calculations in pixels manually, but this would get ugly.